# Finding singularities in circle of convergence of $f(z)$ and showing taylor series diverges there

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f(x)=\arctan(x)$$

I know that $$\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-x)^i$$

Also:  $$\arctan(x)=\int \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \int \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-x)^i dx = x - 0.5x^2+1/3x^3+\cdots=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i(x)^{i+1}}{2i+1}$$

Radius of convergence $R = 1$ using ratio test $\implies |z|\le1$ is the circle of convergence

Singularities are at $\pm i$ and both lie in $|z|$ however how do i show that the series diverges there?

**EDIT:**

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 +\cdots + (-1)^kx^{2k} + \cdots\to \int \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}.$$

Comment: The series and the summation should have $-x^2$, not $-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe: $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 +\cdots + (-1)^kx^{2k} + \cdots\to \int \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}.$$ When $ x = \pm i$, the series equals $\pm i\cdot \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2k+1} = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

If a power series converges in some point $x_0$, then the derivation also converges
 in the point $x_0$. Here, the derivation diverges at $x_0=-1$ and $x_0=1$, so the
 original power series diverges there as well.

Comment: The first statement is false. Consider $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ in $x_0=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac 1 {1+x^2} = \frac 1 {(x-i)(x+i)} = \frac {i/2} {x+i} - \frac{i/2}{x-i}
$$
In a small neighborhood of $i$ this is a continuous function plus $\text{constant}/(x-i)$.

Think of what happens to a function whose derivative is $1/(x-i)$ as $x$ approaches $i$ from the positive real direction.  If $x$ is approaching from that direction, then $x-i$ is real, and the antiderivative of $1/(x-i)$ at least on the ray going in that direction from $i$ will be a constant plus $\log(x-i)$.  That function has a pole.